# Change excel vba tickmark (y-axis) spacing

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

How can I adjust the spacing between value labels (y-axis) in excel vba? I want to do it in absolute terms like have steps of 5000 in between.

My code looks along the lines of this:

```
With createChart.Chart
    
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 230
    .Type = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Liquiditätsverlauf"
    '.ApplyLayout (4)
    With .Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = -50000 * (1 - padding)
        .MaximumScale = 200000 * (1 + padding)
        .HasMajorGridlines = True
        .MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        .MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDash
        .MajorTickMark = xlTickMarkOutside
        .TickMarkSpacing = 10 'these two don't work for value axis :/
        .TickLabelSpacing = 10
    End With
End With
```

Unfortunately the .TickSpacing and .TickLabelSpacing properties don't work for the value axis.

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to specify `.MaximumScale = 155000` and `.MajorUnit = 5000` or something like that to get that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Works flawlessly thank you!